# Rust book ch 13 Closures + HashMap exercise

Tags: rust, hash-map

So the exercise is as follows:

> Try modifying Cacher to hold a hash map rather than a single value.
>   The keys of the hash map will be the arg values that are passed in,
>   and the values of the hash map will be the result of calling the
>   closure on that key. Instead of looking at whether self.value directly
>   has a Some or a None value, the value function will look up the arg in
>   the hash map and return the value, if it’s present. If it’s not
>   present, the Cacher will call the closure and save the resulting value
>   in the hash map associated with its arg value.
>
> Another problem with the current Cacher implementation is that it only
>   accepts closures that take one parameter of type u32 and return an
>   u32. We might want to cache the results of closures that take a string
>   slice and return usize values, for example. To fix this issue, try
>   introducing more generic parameters to increase the flexibility of the
>   Cacher functionality

I tried to make Cacher as generic as I could so it could cache any type of K/V combination.  I am looking for feedback on how I could've done it better.  If there are any antipatterns in my approach. Am I making any foundational mistakes?

My implementation of it is as under:

lib.rs

```
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;
use std::error::Error;


// fn simulated_expensive_calculation(intensity: u32) ->u32 {
//     println!("Calculating slowly...");
//     thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(2));
//     intensity
// }

pub fn run() -> Result<(),Box<dyn Error>> {
    let simulated_user_specified_value = 10;
    let simulated_random_number = 7;

    generate_workout(
        simulated_user_specified_value,
        simulated_random_number
    );
    Ok(())
}

use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::ops::Fn;

struct Cacher<K, V, T>
    where T: Fn(K) -> V,
    K: std::cmp::Eq + std::hash::Hash,
{
    calculation: T,
    values: HashMap<K, V>,
}


use std::collections::hash_map::Entry;

impl <K, V, T> Cacher<K, V, T>
    where T: Fn(K) -> V,
          K: std::cmp::Eq
           + std::hash::Hash
           + std::marker::Copy
           + std::fmt::Debug,
          V: std::fmt::Debug
{
    fn new<E,F>(calculation: T) -> Cacher<E, F, T>
      where T: Fn(E) -> F,
            E: std::cmp::Eq + std::hash::Hash
    {
        Cacher {
            calculation,
            values: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }


    fn value(&mut self, arg: &K) -> &V {
        /* eprintln!("arg: {:?}", *arg);
        let e = self.values.entry(*arg).or_insert((self.calculation)(*arg));
        e
        */
        if let Entry::Vacant(o) = self.values.entry(*arg) {
            o.insert((self.calculation)(*arg));
        }
        &self.values[arg]
    }
}

fn generate_workout(intensity: u32, random_number: u32) {
   let mut expensive_closure = Cacher::new(|intensity| {
        println!("Calculating slowly...");
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(5));
        intensity
   });
   if intensity < 25 {
        println!(
            "Today, do {} pushups!",
            expensive_closure.value(&intensity)
        );
        println!(
            "Next, do {} situps!",
            expensive_closure.value(&intensity)
        );
    } else {
        if random_number == 3 {
            println!("Take a break today! Remember to stay hydrated!");
        } else {
            println!(
                "Today, run for {} minutes!",
                expensive_closure.value(&intensity)
            );
        }
    }
}
```

main.rs:

```
extern crate workout;

use std::process;

fn main() {
    if let Err(e) = workout::run() {
        eprintln!("Application error {}", e);
        process::exit(1);
    }
}
```

## Code on rust playground

*slightly modified so you can simply cut and paste it in foo.rs and run it without creating a whole thing* -- hehe pun intended

```
use std::process;

fn main() {
    if let Err(e) = workout::run() {
        eprintln!("Application error {}", e);
        process::exit(1);
    }
}

mod workout {
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;
use std::error::Error;


// fn simulated_expensive_calculation(intensity: u32) ->u32 {
//     println!("Calculating slowly...");
//     thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(2));
//     intensity
// }

pub fn run() -> Result<(),Box<dyn Error>> {
    let simulated_user_specified_value = 10;
    let simulated_random_number = 7;

    generate_workout(
        simulated_user_specified_value,
        simulated_random_number
    );
    Ok(())
}

use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::ops::Fn;

struct Cacher<K, V, T>
    where T: Fn(K) -> V,
    K: std::cmp::Eq + std::hash::Hash,
{
    calculation: T,
    values: HashMap<K, V>,
}


use std::collections::hash_map::Entry;

impl <K, V, T> Cacher<K, V, T>
    where T: Fn(K) -> V,
          K: std::cmp::Eq
           + std::hash::Hash
           + std::marker::Copy
           + std::fmt::Debug,
          V: std::fmt::Debug
{
    fn new<E,F>(calculation: T) -> Cacher<E, F, T>
      where T: Fn(E) -> F,
            E: std::cmp::Eq + std::hash::Hash
    {
        Cacher {
            calculation,
            values: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }


    fn value(&mut self, arg: &K) -> &V {
        /* eprintln!("arg: {:?}", *arg);
        let e = self.values.entry(*arg).or_insert((self.calculation)(*arg));
        e
        */
        if let Entry::Vacant(o) = self.values.entry(*arg) {
            o.insert((self.calculation)(*arg));
        }
        &self.values[arg]
    }
}

fn generate_workout(intensity: u32, random_number: u32) {
   let mut expensive_closure = Cacher::new(|intensity| {
        println!("Calculating slowly...");
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(5));
        intensity
   });
   if intensity < 25 {
        println!(
            "Today, do {} pushups!",
            expensive_closure.value(&intensity)
        );
        println!(
            "Next, do {} situps!",
            expensive_closure.value(&intensity)
        );
    } else {
        if random_number == 3 {
            println!("Take a break today! Remember to stay hydrated!");
        } else {
            println!(
                "Today, run for {} minutes!",
                expensive_closure.value(&intensity)
            );
        }
    }
}

}
```